# Would a huge screen/projector be healthier for the eyes?

Tags: work-environment, health, ergonomics

As a very common exercise supposed to save your eyes whilst working long term in front of a monitor is to "look twenty feet away for twenty seconds every twenty minutes" and that's apparently the distance your lenses relax fully, I wondered whether it would make sense from a eye health perspective to use it for home office. Occasionally there are tasks where I wouldn't need multiple screens anyways.

I am currently setting up a home cinema system based on an FHD projector and a canvas roughly 17 feet away and am wondering if a similar setup would be good for my home office.

Has someone thought of or tried this before?

Comment: I feel this is not on topic here. Maybe it would be better suited for Medical Sciences as this is more a topic about health statistics?

Comment: You also need to take into account what you are looking at.  Will your projector (and don't forget the screen is a part of this equation) display video with the same fidelity and luminosity as a monitor?

Comment: @Lehue If the question as frames was "My boss is replacing all of our monitors with projectors because he says it is better for our eyes", then it would be on topic.  But the "I'm doing it for my home office" aspect  IMHO makes it off topic.

Comment: Theoretically it's very possible, but I don't know how much practical it would be. I'll not be able to concentrate much for a long time on a 20-feet away screen.

Comment: As a hint: for entertainment, projector + screen might be better than large TV. Plenty of discussions on the net, just use your favorite search engine. For productivity, you usually need to see details, which is not attainable at a big distance == screen must be relatively close to you. Moreover, in the office it is impractical for everybody to have projectors + screens. Make a test: place your monitor(s) at double distance, compared to now. Then triple the distance. Analyze the results.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced this is off-topic. The [ergonomics](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/ergonomics/info) tag makes no mention of home office considerations vs business offices and the existence of a telecommuting tag implies that questions regarding working from home are on-topic. It'd be a bit odd for telecommuting questions to be on topic but not questions about the home office but perhaps that's the case. I've asked a [question on meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6446/are-ergonomics-questions-regarding-home-offices-off-topic).

Comment: @SouravGhosh I read entire books this way, if you need glasses to work on a normal screen, the relief of not using them makes it worthwhile... I don't use it at the same resolution obviously as my normal monitor, and sometimes scale up the font size. You tweak it to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried a big monitor about 15 feet away and up high and it does work. I'm not sure what size it is, but probably around 50 inch wall mounted.

Getting older I'm starting to have eyesight issues and cannot use my laptop without glasses. I have a large monitor attached to the laptop which is a lot better but I'm noticing that is deteriorating as well.

I find the big screen at the other end of the room to be great as I do not need glasses at all. I tend to use it for certain tasks though which involve scrolling a lot of code or diagrams looking for problems. Other things like right now with a lot of typing I prefer to sit at my desk. I haven't attempted using it from my desk.

This isn't a medical opinion, I'm no sort of doctor, just something that works for me.

Comment: A 50" screen at 15 feet away seems way too small to work on... that's a ~14 degree viewing angle, roughly equivalent to working on a desktop monitor that's only 8".

Comment: @NuclearWang maybe it's bigger? Not really sure the size, but you're only saying that, yet I'm actually doing it, so ... I'm right, you're wrong.... no offence

Comment: I don't know what could be considered "wrong" in my comment... the screen's angular size is just math, and an 8" screen is very tiny by pretty much any standard, so the only remaining possibility is that your measurements are mistaken.

Comment: @NuclearWang or that my eyesight at anything over normal screen distance is excellent.... who knows... but it works, I read entire books like this. Resolution and font size are tweaked obviously just as they are for a normal monitor

Comment: @NuclearWang there is a third possibility.  It is possible that despite the math being correct, the two experiences are not in fact the same.